# address returned is not what's stored in the value

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm trying to debug a small C++ program using gdb, but may be getting hung up on some pointer arithmetic:

`A* get(int)` returns a pointer to an instance of a class `A` I've defined. Internally, `get(int)` references an array of `A`, returning:

```
class A_list {
  private:
    A* A_array;
    int count;
  public:
    A_list(int c): count(c) { A = new A[c]; }
    void insertAt(A a, int idx) {
      A_array[idx] = a;
    }
    A* get(int);
};

A* A_list::get(int idx) {
...
A* result = A_array + idx;

return result;
}
```

presumably, when dealing with an array of `A`, I can simply add the index (times the size of a single `A`) to get the address of the `idx`'th.

This seems to work as expected. However, when calling `get(int)` from within another member function of `A_list`, I watch the value assignment in gdb and see two different values:

```
void A_list::foo() {
  A* a = nullptr; // I declare my pointer, and initialize to 0x0 
  ...
  a = get(0); // I store the address of `A_array[0]`
```

The `gdb` watchpoint outputs:

```
Old value = (Number *) 0x0
New value = (Number *) 0x55555556b2c0
```

However, when I print the address stored in `a`, I get a completely different value, with an unrecognized message attached.

```
(gdb) p a
(Number *) 0x7ffff7b4e5c0 <_IO_file_overflow+256>
```

attempting to dereference any of the member values gives unexpected results

I can't find `<_IO_file_overflow+256>` defined anywhere in the gdb sources. What does it mean?

Why might the value stored in `a` appear to be different from the value returned when `get()` is called from inside a member function of `A_list`? From outside (eg - in `main()`) I get the expected value.

Edit 9-08:
Changed assignment in get() based on feedback. Still getting the same arbitrary address when I return from the `get()` function.

Comment: skipping the call to `get(int)` altogether, and just assigning `a = A_list + i` has the same problem. Even though `p A_list
$2 = (A *) 0x55555556b2c0` and `p i$3 = 0`, `p a
$1 = (A *) 0x7ffff7b4e5c0 <_IO_file_overflow+256>`

Comment: By the way, you *do* follow [the rules of three or five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? Since you have a raw non-owning pointer you really need to do that.

Comment: I do not. Putting together an example, but not able to trigger the same issue. I'm assuming that my original code is suffering without the destructor / copy constructor / copy assignment.

Answer (score 1):

When doing pointer arithmetic, it's done in *elements* and not in units of bytes.

Therefore the multiplication with `sizeof(A)` is invalid and wrong: The expression `A_array + (idx * sizeof(A))` should be plain `A_array + idx`.

Or you could be explicit and return `&A_array[idx]`.

---

All this means that for any pointer or array `a` and (valid) index `i`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* the same as `a[i]`. And from that follows that `&a[i]` will be exactly the same as `a + i`.

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed the syntax in my post. From my comment above, I'd expect `A* a = A_list + i` to give me a pointer to the i'th element in `A_list`. However, I'm still getting what looks like an arbitrary address. Doesn't seem to matter how I'm computing the address.

Comment: @donny-nyc What we really need is a proper [mre]. You're probably doing something in the code you don't show us, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question -- `<_IO_file_overflow+256>` is telling you gdb's best guess as to what that address (0x7ffff7b4e5c0) refers to -- in this case, the address is pointing into some shared libaray, and the symbol `_IO_file_overflow` is the closest symbol defined in that library (and specifically, this address is 256 bytes past that symbol).  This looks to be part of libc.

You can get more detail about what addresses correspond to what in your program by examining the file /proc/*<pid>*/maps -- you just need to know the pid of the process you are debugging and you can look at that file in another window.

As to *why* you're getting this odd value when it looks like you've just assigned a different value, it may be that gdb is getting confused and you have another `a` defined somewhere and gdb is printing that.  Or you may have incomplete/incorrect debugging info in your program -- make sure that you compile with `-O0 -g` if you want accurate debug info.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what the symbol meant (and where it was coming from). I had set `-O0` and `-g` to no avail...